# Adding Rule into existing KiePackage and KieBase

Tags: java, drools, kie

I'm trying to add a Rule to a KiePackage that has already been defined and built using KieBuilder.

I know you can remove a rule using:

```
base.removeRule("com.somepackage", "ruleName");
```

But is there an equivalent for adding a rule? I've tried adding a new .drl file into the KieFileSystem and using KieScanner to pick up the changes, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
KieBaseConfiguration config = service.newKieBaseConfiguration();
KieBase base = kContainer.newKieBase(config);

KieFileSystem fileSystem = service.newKieFileSystem(); 
KieBuilder builder = service.newKieBuilder(fileSystem); 

fileSystem.write(originalDrlFile, someFile)    
builder.buildAll()                               // first drl is loaded

fileSystem.write(newlDrlFile, someFile)    

KieScanner scanner = service.newKieScanner(kContainer);
scanner.scanNow();
KieSession ksession1 = kContainer.newKieSession();    

builder.buildAll()                               // reloading with new drl.
```

When I evaluate a fact against ksession1, the new rules dont exist in the KieBase. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

```
private KieSession kieSession;
public void build() throws Exception {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream( "override/r2.drl" );
    kfs.write( "src/main/resources/r2.drl",
                kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis2 ) );
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream( "override/r1.drl" );
    kfs.write( "src/main/resources/r1.drl",
                kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis1 ) );

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();

    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
        System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
        throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
    }

    KieContainer kieContainer =
        kieServices.newKieContainer( kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );

    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

The `build` method illustrates an incremental build. To add a rule, you can do the entire process using an additional DRL file with the new rule once more. Or, if you keep the KieFileSystem, you can add the DRL file later, call buildAll once more, recreate the KieBase, etc.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. I tried writing a new drl file to the existing KieFileSystem, then calling kieBuilder.buildAll(). But when I create a new KieContainer and KieBase afterwards, the new rules aren't there. Am I missing a step?

Comment: @laune answer is good, in my case i just keep the KieFileSystem, adding new DRLs, recall builder/kiecontainer and recreate session.

Comment: @laune Is there a way to get or even set the rule name somewhere near  `kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource(...);` if the resource is of type `ResourceType DRL`?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral You define rule names when you write the DRL file.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. I am trying to retrieve the rule name my user's defining when they are writing the rule and before I compile the rule to create `KieContainer`. I asked a proper question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555949/retrieve-rule-name-in-drools-without-building-kiecontainer), would appreciate your help big time.

Answer (score 0):

Where are we making a relationship between the kieBuilder and kieBase?

I have tried something like this..

```
kieContainer= kieService.newKieContainer(kiebuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

Comment: You can ask it as different question, instead of asking it in an answer.

Comment: I have just added as a suggestion.. Just to know why they haven't used this. @LuFFy